# Conditionally formatting a cell based on exact match using an existing Color map

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

This might be a basic question, but I am looking for an elegant solution to this, preferably without using VBA.

**Problem:** I have a color map table which is basically a large number of formatted cells (cell colors), each cell with a specific value. Then, in another table, I have these values occurring in multiple rows and columns. I want to use this color map table to match the values of cells in the table (similar to conditional formatting) and apply the color/formatting.

Here is a miniature example. The color map contains a cell with the value "D" which is colored red. So, every cell in the Sample table which contains "D" needs to be colored red as well. And this needs to happen for every cell in Sample Table, and every value in the color map table, as illustrated below -

[image]

The challenge is that when using conditional formatting, I have to make individual conditions for each, and explicitly fill the required format if it matches. This is difficult since the color map in actual data is 100s of keys and corresponding colors, and the sample table is also quite elaborate.

Have spent some time on the web but didn't find a solution to this.

- I found a few solutions on SO which might help me use VBA to pull colors from color map table cells and apply them to sample table cells, but I don't know if that is the most optimal approach to this problem and would want to avoid that approach unless absolutely necessary.
- Another option I have is using the Python code that generates the color map, and leveraging that to directly generate the sample table with colored cells, which is potentially an easier approach for me. However, is there a way I could just use Excel to do this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, Conditional Formatting was not intended for this type of situations. Maybe some Add-in or as you mentioned using VBA or Excel JavaScript with Script Lab Add-in.

Comment: Thanks @DavidLeal, yea it seemed that way, especially since I couldn't find anything as is on SO and my general Google research. For the time being, I have saved the hex codes from the random color generator in python as a dictionary and will use that to prepopulate this take with colored cells using some python excel extensions. Will explore VBA and Excel JS options as well.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal conditional formatting to this degree would probably be a rough experience even if you were to manually add in all of the conditions. If you do explore the python route, Openpyxl, and specifically openpyxl.styles will be able to do what you are wanting and do all the work on the front end so that the workbook doesn't have to be bogged down.